# java 8 doesn't support sun.awt?

Tags: java, awt

A client on windows xp pro x32 just updated java to java8 u45 b14 (from java7) and started getting `NoClassDefFoundError` on `sun.awt.VerticalBagLayout`

Reverting back to Java7 resolved the issue.

Has oracle discontinued support for sun.awt classes?

Comment: The sun.awt classes are not supposed to be used. They are described as implementation details. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941337/com-sun-awt-package-usage

Comment: See [Note about sun.* packages](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html).

Comment: @EJP thanks. I guess I will have to find a replacement for that class then...

Comment: This question is not at all an exact duplicate. What Java supports and what constitutes bad practice are two very different things. I just compiled with Java 8 using sun.awt and I did not have any problems using sun.awt.AWTAccessor and a number of other classes. It's possible they have changed the implementation in 8 and removed VerticalBagLayout. If you understand the risks and limitations and test properly there's no reason not to use classes.