# setUndecorated not working with non-default look and feel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Frame {

    private JFrame jFrame;

    public Frame() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void create() {
        jFrame = new JFrame("frame");
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame().create();
    }

}
```

The code above works fine but if I set jFrame.undecorated to true, it doesn't remove the frame? Does anyone know why not? Thanks.

Edit: Also found that if I set jFrame.undecorated to false, another frame with default look and feel also displays. Like this:

[image: example]

Comment: please my question is - in Win8 & Java7?

Comment: AFAIK there is issue with  [Transparency and undecorated container in Java7(OS isn't important)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219111/cant-transparent-and-undecorated-jframe-in-jdk7-when-enabling-nimbus)

Answer (score 1):

Check the doc on the setUndecorated() method - can only be called when not visible.  Your code with the two calls commented out in the constructor, but added jFrame.setUndecorated(true); before the setVisible() call.

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Frame {

private JFrame jFrame;

public Frame() {
    try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        //JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        //JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void create() {
    jFrame = new JFrame("frame");
    jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setSize(200, 200);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame().create();
}

}
```

Comment: Yes I knew that it to be not visible. With the JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true); commented, the JFrame is not going to display the look and feel. Also, I want to be able to remove the frame with the click of a button which, setUndecorated(true) does not work.

Comment: So I wonder if doing something like minimizing the frame, then setting to undecorated would still be considered as 'not visible'?  Guessing not but might be worth a try.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with it being visible, as i said above, setting the undecorated flag to true, whether it's visible or not, does not removed the frame.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, what worked for me:

`setUndecorated(true)` inside the Constructor of frame you want to have undecorated.
In the main class **before** setting Look and Feel instantiate the Object (your Frame). Once called `setVisible` down the road it worked for me.

Comment: `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)` will not effect the JFrame if if you invoke the method **after** JFrame is initialized. 
`Provides a hint as to whether or not newly created JFramesshould have their Window decorations (such as borders, widgets toclose the window, title...) provided by the current lookand feel` - `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)` Javadoc