# how to set semi-transparent jframe when "submit" button is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency

```
loadingLab=new JLabel("The name is being saved..");
loadPanel.add(loadingLab);
submitBttn=new JButton("Submit");
submitBttn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
        System.out.println("Submit Button Clicked!!");
        try {
            //something is wrong in here as it throws an exception
            //what is wrong?
            frame.setUndecorated(false);
            frame.setOpacity(0.55f);

            //when above both lines are commented, the code works fine
            //but doesnt have transparency  
            frame.add(loadPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

I am trying to display transparent `JFrame` when "submit" button is clicked which displays panel with a `JLabel`...
I have tried using `setOpacity(0.55f)`, but it throws exception.. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: The frame has to be undecorated in order to achieve this (you did `frame.setUndecorated(false);`). Also, if you make the existing frame undecorated inside the actionlistener, you will have to call `frame.dispose()` before it (and `frame.setVisible(true)` after it)

Comment: @LuxxMiner    thanx for suggestion....

Comment: there I'm can't see any exception in Java6, 7 or 8

Comment: @LuxxMiner i did the above , no exception and there is transparency, however, the frame close button has disappeared .. and panel (loadPanel)  is not opaque

Comment: @mKorbel , the exception is " java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable."

Comment: @LuxxMiner i dont see how it is any different..

Comment: @Programmer007 Well, it works for me in my code... I will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I think there's no way to keep the system window decoration, you will probably have to go with the default one. Since I'm not 100% sure if you want to toggle the opacity of the whole frame or just the frame's background, I've included both functions in my example. (mKorbels answer help you more if you don't want to have a decoration)

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class TransparentExample extends JFrame {

    public TransparentExample() {

        super("TransparentExample");
        Color defaultBackground = getBackground();
        float defaultOpacity = getOpacity();

        JToggleButton button1 = new JToggleButton("Toggle background transparency");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (button1.isSelected()) {
                    setBackground(new Color(defaultBackground.getRed(), defaultBackground.getGreen(),
                            defaultBackground.getBlue(), 150));
                } else {
                    setBackground(defaultBackground);
                }
            }
        });

        JToggleButton button2 = new JToggleButton("Toggle opacity of whole frame");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
                if (button2.isSelected()) {
                    setOpacity(0.55f);
                } else {
                    setOpacity(defaultOpacity);
                }
                setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(button1);
        getContentPane().add(button2);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                TransparentExample frame = new TransparentExample();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Picture of frame with no togglebutton selected:
[image]

Picture of frame with the first togglebutton selected:
[image]

Picture of frame with the second togglebutton selected:
[image]

Comment: thank you very much... i was definately looking for second togglebutton (setting the opacity)..my another question is, how do u make it's panel opaque with background semi-transparent

Comment: @Programmer007 Well, if you don't mind that the decoration isn't semi-transparent, you could stick with the first button and replace `setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` with `setBackground(new Color(defaultBackground.getRed(), defaultBackground.getGreen(), defaultBackground.getBlue(), 150));`. That would make the background semi-transparent, but every component (the buttons) fully visible (including an added panel, in your case. As long as you didn't call `setOpaque(false)` on it, it should work).

Comment: the semi-transparent worked... will work on opaque panel now

Comment: @Programmer007 So is this now the end result you wanted? I don't understand what you mean with *"will work on opaque panel now"*... Was that a question? If yes, I guess you're referring to the `loadPanel` in your code. Well... Yes, you can set the background to `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)` for that, the background color will stay the same. (If that's what you were asking)

Comment: i was asking, only when "submit " button is clicked , the frame turns semi-transparent and it displays panel (loadPanel-which is actually opaque)

Comment: can somebody show me an example of how to set panel opaque with semi transparent frame in background....

Comment: @Programmer007 Combined with the function of my first button you can just add the panel, it will be opaque (frame background will still be semi-transparent.

Answer (score 1):

> @Programmer007 wrote - the exception is "
>   java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable."

- please where I can't see any, for more info [about the possible exceptions to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219111/cant-transparent-and-undecorated-jframe-in-jdk7-when-enabling-nimbus),
- as mentioned no idea, everything is about your effort, transformed to the SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GenericForm extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Timer timer;
    private JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    private int count = 0;

    public GenericForm() {
        dialog.setSize(400, 300);
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        dialog.setOpacity(0.5f);
        dialog.setName("Toggling with opacity");
        dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        dialog.setLocation(150, 150);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1500, updateCol());
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    private Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("Hello World") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean bol = dialog.getOpacity() < 0.55f;
                count += 1;
                if (count < 10) {
                    if (bol) {
                        dialog.setOpacity(1.0f);
                        dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        dialog.setOpacity(0.5f);
                        dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GenericForm();
            }
        });
    }
}
```